Why is my n-gram statistic so slow?
To learn a bit about the Mathematica language, I set me the task to generate sentences of russian letters randomly which respect letter n-gram probability drawn from a longer russian text.
As a text I chose the russian wikipedia entry for Fjodor Dostoevsky, and I used the following functions:
(* ::Package:: *)

getWikipediaText[lemma_, lang_]:=
Module[
{rule, text},
rule = Select[WikipediaData[lemma, "TitleTranslationRules"] ,ToString[#[[1]]]==lang &];
text = WikipediaData[lang /. rule, Language->lang];
text
]



ngramStat[lis_, test_, n_]:=
Module[
{lisAkt = lis, res = {}},
While[Length[lisAkt] > n,
If[Take[lisAkt,n] == test, res = Append[res, lisAkt[[n+1]]]];
lisAkt = Drop[lisAkt,1]];
res
]



russWord[start_,text_, m_, n_]:=
Module[
{primer = Characters[ToLowerCase[start]], res, ngs,
freq, freqTotal, freq1, wd, newChar},
res = primer;
While[Length[res] < n,
ngs = ngramStat[text, primer, m];
freq = Tally[ToLowerCase[ngs]];
freqTotal = Total[#[[2]] & /@ freq];
freq1 = {#[[1]],N[#[[2]]/freqTotal]} & /@ freq;
wd = WeightedData @@ Transpose[freq1];
newChar = RandomChoice[wd,1][[1]];
res = Append[res, newChar];
Print["res = ", StringJoin[res]];
primer = Drop[Append[primer, newChar], 1];
];
res
]

The results are amusing (I am now calculating letter-trigram-predictions) but terribly slow. Main culprit is the function ngramStat which needs about ten seconds to produce its result.
Why these slowness? (I did not compare it with a similar python code, but I have the feeling, something is terribly wrong here - this is on an (albeit 8 year old) Xeon Workstation).
Just for completeness: The notebook code:
text = getWikipediaText["Dostoevsky", "Russian"];

StringTake[text, 300]

alfa = Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" "}]

text1 = Characters[text];

russWord[StringJoin[alfa[[{1, 2}]]], text1, 2, 130]

and the result of first run :-)
аболленут травнажестого вы и кого да на бода котечинска, жизм».
вскогиях одень бытизак иг, ду свидрудок выховаличестан зетельне
EDIT: I dug further in the Mathematica documentation and noticed a very useful function here, namely Subsequences[] and rewrote my bad ngramStat more in the Mathematica spirit
ngramStat[lis_, test_, n_]:=
Module[
{biglis, res = {}},
biglis = Subsequences[lis,{n+1}];
Scan[If[Take[#,n] == test, res = Append[res, #[[n+1]]]]&, biglis];
res
]

It has now acceptable runtimes, although I suspect that in C# (just to name a language I have come to esteem over using it professionally) it would be even faster.
Finally my last try:
ngramStat[lis_, test_, n_]:=
Module[
{biglis, res},
biglis = Subsequences[lis,{n+1}];
biglis = Select[biglis, Take[#,n] == test &];
res = #[[n+1]] & /@ biglis;
res
]

Looks Mmaish for me and shortens execution time from 0.6s to 0.5s.
EDIT 2: In the meantime I found a really good way of calculating n-grams which uses (unsurprisingly) Associations. This lead me to
ngramStatTotal[lis_,n_] :=
Module[
{biglis, ass},
biglis = Partition[lis, n+1, 1];
biglis = {Take[#,n],#[[n+1]]} & /@ biglis;

ass = Association[];
Scan[(ass[ #[[1]] ] = {}) &, biglis];

Scan[(ass[#[[1]]]= Append[ass[#[[1]]],#[[2]]]) &, biglis];
ass
]


randomText[start_,text_, m_, n_]:=
Module[
    {primer = Characters[ToLowerCase[start]], res, ngsTotal, sample, newChar},
    res = primer;
    ngsTotal = ngramStatTotal[text, m];
    While[Length[res] < n,
        If[KeyExistsQ[ngsTotal,primer],
            sample = ngsTotal[primer];
          newChar = RandomSample[sample,1][[1]],
          newChar = start[[1]]
        ];
        
        AppendTo[res, newChar];

        primer = Drop[Append[primer, newChar], 1];
    ];
    StringJoin[res]
]


I'm not sure I understand the full code yet, but for calculating n-gram frequencies why not use LetterCounts?

Append and *Sequence* functions are known for slowing down calculations. If you change this question to "How to efficiently find n-gram frequencies from text", it will get you the right answers.

There may be faster ways, but I think it makes it easier if you calculate the n-gram frequencies and randomly sample from them like this

I am not able to follow the code, but using Subsequences seems like it will give non-contiguous n-grams. Is that desired?

@Daniel Lichtblau I took from the documentation that Subsequences[lis,{n}] produces only contiguous sequences. For example Subsequences[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3}] gives me {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}.

Sorry, I managed to miss that. I’m still pretty confused though. Is the goal of the stats part to get counts of all trigrams appearing in the text? Tally[Partition[lis,n,1]] might be along those lines if so.

@Daniel Lichtblau Many thanks for pointing out the Partition[lis, n, 1] function. It is seemingly equivalent to Subsequences[lis, {n}], but for lis=Range[200000] it is 10 times faster on my machine.

(1) I am beginning to see how this is done. I have another possible approach to gathering the stats. It returns tallied pairs of the form {chartriple, nextchar}. The tally value can be used for weight purposes in generating random "sentences". ngramStatTotal2[lis_, n_] := Module[{biglis = Partition[lis, n + 1, 1]},   biglis = {Take[#, n], #[[n + 1]]} & /@ biglis;   Tally[biglis]]

(2) Example: `In[260]:= ngramStatTotal2[text1, 3][[100 ;; 110]]
Out[260]= {{{{"-", "П", "е"}, "т"}, 3}, {{{"П", "е", "т"}, "е"},
18}, {{{"е", "т", "е"}, "р"}, 22}, {{{"т", "е", "р"}, "б"},
20}, {{{"е", "р", "б"}, "у"}, 19}, {{{"р", "б", "у"}, "р"},
19}, {{{"б", "у", "р"}, "г"}, 21}, {{{"у", "р", "г"}, ")"},
1}, {{{"р", "г", ")"}, " "}, 1}, {{{"г", ")", " "}, "[LongDash]"},
1}, {{{")", " ", "[LongDash]"}, " "}, 6}}` Also this is somewhat faster than the code you have at present.

I refactored some and also removed characters from the text that are not in the alphabet. That step can be omitted if you prefer to use all characters found in the text.
This gets the text, removes those extraneous characters, and creates a list of the frequencies of the ones we retain. We use this only for the case where we need to generate a random character because the lookup failed due to absence of a given key.
text = getWikipediaText["Dostoevsky", "Russian"];
alfa = Join[Alphabet["Russian"], {" "}];
charalts = Alternatives @@ alfa;
text1 = Select[Characters[text], MatchQ[#, charalts] &];
{chars, freqs} = Transpose[Tally[text1]];

Here is code to create the lookup association.
ngramStatTotal[lis_, n_] := 
 Module[{biglis = Partition[lis, n + 1, 1], prefixes},
  biglis = {Take[#, n], #[[n + 1]]} & /@ biglis;
  prefixes = GatherBy[Tally[biglis], #[[1, 1]] &];
  Apply[Association, 
   Flatten@Map[{#[[1, 1, 1]] -> {#[[All, 1, 2]], #[[All, 2]]}} &, 
     prefixes]]
  ]

--- edit ---
It seems I liked a different variation more, and forgot to note it. Here is the code for gramStatTotal2.
ngramStatTotal2[lis_, n_] := 
 Module[{biglis = Partition[lis, n + 1, 1], prefixes},
  biglis = {Take[#, n], #[[n + 1]]} & /@ biglis;
  prefixes = GatherBy[Tally[biglis], First];
  Apply[Association, 
 Flatten@Map[{#[[1, 1, 1]] -> {#[[All, 1, 2]], #[[All, 2]]}} &, 
   prefixes]]
  ]

--- end edit
It is fairly fast for e.g. trigrams.
Timing[nt = ngramStatTotal2[text1, 3];]

(* Out[81]= {0.154631, Null} *)

To see what it provides, here are a few elements.
In[82]:= nt[[1 ;; 3]]
(* Out[82]= <|{"ё", "д", "о"} -> {50} -> {"р"}, {"д", "о",
"р"} -> {28, 10, 23} -> {" ", "а", "о"}, {"о", "р",
" "} -> {19, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1} -> {"и", "о", "б",
"к", "н", "м", "с", "п", "т", "д", " ", "ё", "у"}|> *)
We have a key for each trigram. The value is a rule associating a set of weights (from number of appearances) with potential next characters. We use this to take random samples in the next routine. Note that the computation of the stats association is pulled out since it is the slow step; we do not want to redo it if, say, we are generating a table of random character sequences.
randomText[start_, m_, n_, ngtotals_] := 
 Module[{primer = Characters[ToLowerCase[start]], res, key, sample, 
   newChar},
  res = ConstantArray[" ", n];
  res[[1 ;; m]] = primer;
  Do[key = res[[j ;; j + m - 1]];
   If[KeyExistsQ[ngtotals, key],
    sample = ngtotals[key];
    newChar = RandomSample[sample[[1]], 1];
    ,
    newChar = RandomSample[freqs -> chars, 1];
    ];
   res[[j + m]] = newChar;
   , {j, n - m}];
  StringJoin@res]

Here is an example.
ngsTotal = ngramStatTotal2[text1, 2];
Table[randomText[alfa[[{1, 2}]], 2, 100, ngsTotal], 5]

(* Out[87]= {"абуг о ое  вки  ие со пкеви н леяснщое иеинлнлгдт алороп \
иисрпяаохумхости пе  ихл вуейдыт вияоыое  ж", "абдррокаияеои оарф \
ттвеоачовнеооыьавагжтеу ову вуоатглсквод   лзеда овеуаылвр и сенл \
вкоуне  ы оа  к", "абсаё снтеиоль сов нр ыкан   схр ио лрети \
оозекмеиаооо рийнстх лотгосгярва хб еобз портсбр   сыа и т", "абао \
точенитесачм сй  гием теааилааикайноиои оерьычл в рпр йеви уа  п а \
апкс ед тлокттиёрау и  клвил", "абванот днитие згояен лвпыыпе о е \
олажо апкадар  тлиес солебпеоаоес е оячн  саодёс  нт янулеош оап о"} *)


Could it be that the Output given at Out[82] is from a version of ngramStatTotal that is a bit later/different than the one stated above it? (I tried it with (latin) characters and it gave a different output layout).

Good catch. It must be different; note the use of ngramStatTotal2. I'll see if I can find the actual code.
